# Add to cart function works strange (Virtuemart 2)

Tags: virtuemart

I use Joomla 2.5.28 and Virtumart 2.6.2 for my website. I created many child products for all of my parent products and used plug-ins custom field (stockable variants) to be able to add right variant of product to cart. And everything is ok, except one thing. If I push "Add to cart" button twice on a same product variant, I see two separated identical lines in the shopping cart.

It works this way only for child products. If I just create product without any children, it works fine.

Any ideas why it works this way and how can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your installation is quite old. I'd suggest you to create a demo installation with latest vm version and check if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the Add To Cart button in previous versions of VirtueMart 2.

The latest version 2.6.18 and the upcoming 2.6.20 already have means to prevent a double click on the button.

Please update as soon as possible for security reasons anyway.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. I upgraded my installation to VirtueMart 2.6.20. But unfortunately it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: As far as I know, the prevention of double click works with jQuery. So there might be a jQuery conflict.